# Show that $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$~$t(n-1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be iid random variables, and $X_i$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Show that $\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$~$t(n-1)$
Approach:
To show that $z=\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$~$t(n-1)$, I should show that the numerator is a standard gaussian and the denomenator is chi squared with 1 degree of freedom.
multiply and divide by $1/(\sigma\sqrt{n})$, we get

$\dfrac{(\bar{X}-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{n})}{\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}(\sigma\sqrt{n})}}=\dfrac{(\bar{X}-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{\dfrac{s^2}{\sigma^2 n^2}}}$.

I know $\dfrac{(\bar{X}-\mu)}{(\sigma\sqrt{n})}$ is drawn from a standard gaussian. However, how can I show that $\dfrac{s^2}{\sigma^2 n}$ is drawn from a chia square with 1 degree of freedom?

Comment: First, show that $Q = (n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim CHISQ(n-1).$ Then $T = Z/\sqrt{Q/(n-1)} \sim T(n-1),$ where $Z \sim Norm(0,1).$ The latter step involves a bivariate transformation, perhaps of $(Z,Q)$ to $(Z,T)$ and then integrating out  $Z$ to get the dist'n of the $T$ marginal. All parts are classical proofs and you can probably find them in a math stat text or on the Internet, if you can't manage them on your own.